# How to assign value to a scalar variable in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a `for-loop` and wished to assign the value to the first variable in the part of an array that equals to `-inf`. The complete code is as below:

```
cList = np.full((5), -np.inf)
for i in range(5):
    newest = another_array[i][1]
    cList[cList==-np.inf][0] = newest
```

The code didn't throw any errors. However the value assignment was failed. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
cList[cList==-np.inf]
```

makes a copy of the selected data, not a view, so this:

```
cList[cList==-np.inf][0] = newest
```

modifies the copy, leaving `cList` unchanged.

Repeatedly searching `cList` for instances of `-inf` is a really inefficient way to go about this. The best solution will depend on the details of your program. For the simple example you've posted, you could just do

```
c = another_array[:5, 1].copy()  # or just another_array[:5, 1] if a view is fine
```

For more complex cases, you might want to create an array of values to assign and do

```
c[c == -np.inf] = values
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But how can I modify it to a proper one? Thanks!

Comment: @user5779223: Answer expanded.

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting. So, assigning to a boolean selection works, but not when it is indexed? Why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Assigning to `a[b]` modifies `a`, while assigning to `a[b][c]` modifies `a[b]`.